# Static files don't load in django

Tags: django, static, django-statistics

I have stopped creating new project with django 1.1 and from that time was only working on already created applications. Since then I guess that static serving somehow changed (**project is using Django 1.2.4**). I'm struggling for few hours and with no results, so if somebody knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know.

My settings :

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

SECRET_KEY = '(d9bahjuyy_i-)4b(w9gc5a&s&5jemcn7&b^wrbuemah3p-6^#'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'project',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.csrf",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes' : True}),
)
```

And media files are located in ../project_path/media

In templates I get the {{ MEDIA_URL }} path as /static/ but my files are not loaded. Going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ (with or without last slash) shows root page. Firebug shows the html code of page in place of javascript files. I would rather expect 404 error. Where's the problem ?

---

Swicthed to 1.3 . Problem remains.

Comment: Try django-staticfiles, or even better upgrade to Django 1.3 which includes an improved version: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/

Comment: I have switched to 1.3 and still the same + now STATIC_URL is empty.

Comment: can you show more of your urls.py, I'm guessing you have a regex earlier in your urls that is catching your all the urls before reaching your static serve entry.

Comment: Now that you made it public, perhaps you want to change your SECRET_KEY setting...

Answer (score 7):

Just in case if you are using render_to_response, you have to pass optional 3rd parameter:

```
context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

soe the full code looks like:

```
return render_to_response('index.html',{'dict':'ionary'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

{{ STATIC_URL }} works with RequestContext, while default for render_to_response is Context

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Django's 1.3 `django.contrib.staticfiles`, the app will look for static files under the `static` sub-folder of all your installed apps.  For instance, `staticfiles` will automatically pick up the following css:

```
yourproject/
    appone/
        static/
            sample.css
```

If you are using `django.contrib.staticfiles` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your `settings.py`, you can easily access the css at:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/sample.css
```

For your case, it looks like you have a static folder under your project folder, I will assume the following:

```
yourproject/
    static/
```

If you want `staticfiles` to pick the above, remove the following from `urls.py`:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes' : True}),
```

Add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

In your template, you might want to start using `STATIC_URL` instead of `MEDIA_URL` unless they are both pointing to the same value.

You can read more about [staticfiles in Django 1.3](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/).